# Making a generic descendant of a class containing an interface reference - can someone explain why this crashes?

Tags: delphi, generics, interface, delphi-11-alexandria

I was mystified by an Access Violation in Delphi code I was entrusted to maintain and eventually managed to boil it down to the example below. Any suggestions on how to make the example easier to understand are welcome.

What seems to be happening is, calling the inherited SetInterface method somehow corrupts the FInterface reference, so accessing it via the container thereafter leads to crashes. The original class instance implementing the interface seems to remain uncorrupted, as well as the interface reference outside of container. Re-implementing SetInterface using the generic I type, fixes it.

Is this a Delphi bug or simply a feature ?

(I know that casting the interface back to the implementing class is a bad practice, but the code I am dealing with uses such constructs and I cannot rewrite it all)

```
type
      TInterfaceContainer = class
        FInterface: IInterface;
        procedure SetInterface(const AInterface: IInterface);
        function GetInterface: IInterface;
      end;
      TInterfaceContainerGenericDescendant<I: IInterface> = class(TInterfaceContainer)
        function GetInterface: I;
        //procedure SetInterface(const AInterface: I);  //this fixes the crash, why ?
      end;
    
      ITest = interface
        function GetValue: Int64;
        procedure SetValue(AValue: Int64);
      end;
      TTest = class(TInterfacedObject, ITest)
        FValue: Int64;
        function GetValue: Int64;
        procedure SetValue(AValue: Int64);
      end;
    
    procedure Test;
    begin
      var aInterfaceContainer := TInterfaceContainerGenericDescendant<ITest>.Create;
      try
        var aTest: ITest := TTest.Create;
        aTest.SetValue(11);
        var aTestInstance := aTest as TTest;
        aInterfaceContainer.SetInterface(aTestInstance);
        var aValue := aTest.GetValue;
        aValue := aTestInstance.GetValue;
        aValue := aInterfaceContainer.GetInterface.GetValue;   //AV on this line. Why ?            
      finally
        aInterfaceContainer.Free
      end
    end;


    
    { TInterfaceContainer }
    
    function TInterfaceContainer.GetInterface: IInterface;
    begin
      result := FInterface
    end;
    
    procedure TInterfaceContainer.SetInterface(const AInterface: IInterface);
    begin
      FInterface := AInterface
    end;
    
    { TInterfaceContainerGenericDescendant<I> }
    
    function TInterfaceContainerGenericDescendant<I>.GetInterface: I;
    begin
      result := I(inherited GetInterface)
    end;

    //procedure TInterfaceContainerGenericDescendant<I>.SetInterface( const AInterface: I);
    //begin
    //  inherited SetInterface(AInterface)
    //end;
        
        { TTest }
    
    function TTest.GetValue: Int64;
    begin
      result := FValue
    end;
    
    procedure TTest.SetValue(AValue: Int64);
    begin
      FValue := AValue
    end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you implement some interface with `TInterfacedObject` you have to be aware that this class already implements `IInterface`.

These lines are defective:

```
var aTestInstance := aTest as TTest;
aInterfaceContainer.SetInterface(aTestInstance);
```

What happens here is that in the second line, it gets the `IInterface` reference from `TTest` which inherits from `TInterfacedObject` and thus you get the IMT for `IInterface` - but that one is different from the IMT of `ITest`. Inside your generic class you assume that the `IInterface` you have stored in `TInterfaceContainer` can be hardcasted to `I` which is `ITest` - but because you stored the `IInterface` from `TInterfacedObject` this is a wrong assumption and thus you get the AV because when calling `GetValue` you access a virtual method index (3, the first 3 are those from `IInterface`) that `IInterface` simply does not have and it calls into an invalid code address.

The correction would be this:

```
aInterfaceContainer.SetInterface(aTest);
```

Every interface *is* an `IInterface` - passing the `ITest` reference to the non-generic `SetInterface` ensures that it's the correct IMT and not the one that is *only* an `IInterface` one. Also, this explains why the commented-out method fixes the issue - because then when passing the `TTest` it properly gets the correct IMT for `ITest` from it instead of the `IInterface` one.

I suggest you add the generic more typesafe method to avoid passing `IInterface` references that are not compatible with what you specify for `I` in the generic class.

Comment: by more typesafe, I assume you mean GetInterface, i.e. - inherited GetInterface as I, or even better if not Supports(inherited GetInterface, I, result) then raise ? Hmm, no actually this does not work ..

Comment: I meant adding back what was commented out to avoid passing an `IInterface` that is not an `I`.

Comment: I was hoping to somehow make GetInterface() type-safe, so I'd get a sensible error if I forget to re-define some method when generics-alyzing an existing (complex) class

Comment: The point is that when you can only pass an `I` to `SetInterface` then you automatically ensure that when you `GetInterface` the result is a valid `I`.

Comment: yes I get that in the above example, thanks. I was thinking of a scenario where a class has multiple methods setting the reference, and I miss out on one of them when creating a generic descendant - in such a case having Get() secured would help a lot down the line .. would get a descriptive Exception instead of an AV

Comment: @Peter That is what unit testing is for. If you want to be sure that you don't miss anything, you need to test your classes and their implementations to make sure they work properly.